# "Big budget" vs. "large budget" — which one to use?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns, adjectives, collocation

What is the difference between *big* and *large*? I am trying to use one of these words but I'm skeptical which one is the right one.

The context I intend to use one of these words in is:

> Small companies don't have big/large budgets.

So which one is the better choice?

Comment: Please have a look at our blog post on [Writing good "meaning" questions](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/writing-good-meaning-questions/). Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage stats from the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) look as follows:

```
                       BNC      COCA      

big/large budget      10/9     98/22     
big/large budgets      3/3     25/16
```

So on the east side of the pond, it's a tie, while on the west side, *big* is preferred.

(The numbers have been manually corrected to exclude — lots and lots of —
occurences of *large budget deficits/surpluses/cuts/increases*,
*big budget crisis/fight/debate/gap/deal*, etc.)

Comment: I guess big boys, big shots and big deals become large boys, large shots and large deals when they cross the pond. And largess becomes bigess (pronounced "big-ass") going the other way.

Answer (score 2):

"Large" will always sound [fractionally] more formal than "big" so if in doubt, and you want to sound formal, I would suggest to use "large."

It can also be complicated by context. Recently I corrected "Make a big noise" (referring to the impact of PR events) to "Make a lot of noise."

Not a great improvement, I know, but I felt that "a big noise" simply sounds childish.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any difference in meaning. Often words that we call synonyms have subtle differences in connotation, but in this case, I'm hard pressed to think of any distinction. I don't know why we have both words in English. Use either one.

Comment: Large Brother is watching you. A Big White Butterfly. The Large Bang. Though by and big, the two words are about as synonymous as words get.

Comment: Sure, we've come to expect one or the other in stock phrases, but that doesn't mean that they have different meanings. I presume "Big Brother" used "big" for the alliteration, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rest of the article. Both are acceptable. You may be using large/big to refer to the non-small companies, so you might want to keep the same phrase when discussing the size of the budgets.